# Is there a way to only return certain elements from an array in a mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using the following mongodb query:

```
db.StyleHeader.find({ "FlexContent.ExtendedContent" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Defines" : "Old Keywords" } } }, { "FlexContent.ExtendedContent.Defines" : true, "FlexContent.ExtendedContent.Value" : true }).limit(50);
```

I get the following results :

```
{
  "_id" : 1331142,
  "FlexContent" : {
    "ExtendedContent" : [{
        "Defines" : "Content Keywords",
        "Value" : "FST-SET, SIZING_CHART-WOMENS_SIZING"
      }, {
        "Defines" : "Search Keywords",
        "Value" : "Closeout, Sale, Tops, T-Shirt, Womens"
      }, {
        "Defines" : "Exceptions",
        "Value" : ""
      }, {
        "Defines" : "Old Keywords",
        "Value" : "1020A20,PRT,SML,Let's,Tour,W.,S9S,T,Shirt,By,Twin,Six,#1C,PRINT,SM,1020A20PRTSML,WEBSORTZ,CAT-TOPS-WOMENS-ALL,1020898ZZ,1010A17ZZ,1020A21ZZ,1020902ZZ,1020904ZZ,CAT-TWINSIX,CAT-GIFTIDEAS,CAT-GIFTS-30,CAT-GIFTS-50,1020903ZZ,CAT-GIFTS-NEW,CAT-TOPS-WOMENS-TSHRT,CAT-GIFTS-HER,CAT-TOPS-TSHIRT,SIZING_CHART-WOMENS_SIZING,CAT-GIFTS-ALL,FST.-SET,FGT.-TSHIRT,CAT-SALE-ALL,CAT-SALE-TOPS,ZKQX,CO_01,DIV_00,CAT1_BA,CAT2_AC"
      }, {
        "Defines" : "Name",
        "Value" : "Let's Tour Women's Short Sleeve T Shirt By Twin Six  "
      }, {
        "Defines" : "Base Item",
        "Value" : "1020A20 PRT SML"
      }, {
        "Defines" : "Price",
        "Value" : "21.95"
      }, {
        "Defines" : "Upsells",
        "Value" : "1010A17, 1020898, 1020902, 1020903, 1020904, 1020A21"
      }, {
        "Defines" : "Default Customization Template",
        "Value" : "not applicable"
      }, {
        "Defines" : "Product Description Style",
        "Value" : "None"
      }, {
        "Defines" : "Promo Search",
        "Value" : ""
      }, {
        "Defines" : "Auto Customization",
        "Value" : ""
      }]
  }
}
```

I really only need the ExtendedContent which defines "Search Keywords".

Is there a way to modify my query so that the results looks more like this:

```
{
  "_id" : 1331142,
  "FlexContent" : {
    "ExtendedContent" : [{
        "Defines" : "Search Keywords",
        "Value" : "Closeout, Sale, Tops, T-Shirt, Womens"
      }]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out the query structure first in MongoVUE but ultimately this is going to be done with the C# driver so a solution in either would work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`$` positional projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/#prj._S_) to do this:

```js
db.StyleHeader.find(
    { "FlexContent.ExtendedContent" : { 
        "$elemMatch" : { "Defines" : "Old Keywords" } 
    } },
    { "FlexContent.ExtendedContent.$" : true }
).limit(50);
```

Or even a little simpler (as you're only matching one field in the `ExtendedContent` array elements):

```js
db.StyleHeader.find(
    { "FlexContent.ExtendedContent.Defines" : "Old Keywords" },
    { "FlexContent.ExtendedContent.$" : true }
).limit(50);
```